# SQL Query Question, Find max of result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I am trying create a query that finds a single row with the highest value. I am working in a Oracle 10G environment right now.

I created this query first which lists the quantities

```
SELECT aname, sum(rhowmuch * rhowoften) AS Quantity
FROM ration
GROUP BY ration.aname;

ANAME        QUANTITY
---------- ----------
BLACKIE            16
CONRAD           29.4
MEO                28
MOLLY            37.7
CHUBBLES           75
BOSS             63.7
JEFFREY          29.4
FANNY              56
SUZY               21
ZEO              17.5
MORRIS             21

ANAME        QUANTITY
---------- ----------
SALLY              21
LEO                40
SAM                28

14 rows selected.
```

But I can't figure out a way to create a single query that pulls the maximum quantity from there. Any Suggestions?

Comment: Oracle 10G I'm sorry I didn't specify earlier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.aname, x.quantity
  FROM (SELECT r.name, SUM(r.rhowmuch + r.rhowoften) AS quantity
          FROM RATION r
      GROUP BY r.aname
      ORDER BY quantity DESC) x
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

For more info on using ROWNUM, see: http://blog.lishman.com/2008/03/rownum.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT aname, sum(rhowmuch * rhowoften) AS Quantity
FROM ration
GROUP BY ration.aname
order by Quantity desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Or `SELECT TOP 1...` if using MSSQL.

Comment: I was going to mention that the code can change depending on platform.  My answer is for MySQL.

Comment: Yeah I realized i didn't specify which platform I am in earlier. Oracle 10G seems to be very picky